# How to use the returned value from a C# class in an ASP webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, dll

I am an absolute ASP newbie, but have a very strong PHP/python background, so please bear with me. The C# class talks to a physical weigh scale via serial connection and grabs a weight (This part works great as a standalone .exe that writes to console). However, i'm not sure how to take this working C# class and use it in my ASP webpage?

I have a .cs file that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace AppNamespace {
public class App
{
    static string _somevalue;

    public static string AppDoSomething()
    {
                     // Do some serial port stuff
                     _somevalue = "Hello World or some other value";
                     return _somevalue;
            }
     }
 }
```

This class works great and does what it is supposed to, and i've exported the project and created a .dll library and put it in the "bin" folder of the website.

Now how do I use the the function "AppDoSomething()" in my web page? with PHP I would have done something like the following:

```
<?php 
$value = AppNamespace\App::AppDoSomething();
echo $value;
?>
```

how can I accomplish the same thing using ASP? I Love writing in C#, but don't understand how to integrate C# classes, functions with my asp based webpage, and use them.

Comment: If you can make the dll, then you can add reference to the dll and then access the function like AppNamespace.App.AppDoSomething() in your asp site's server side code.

Comment: the dll is sitting in the bin folder. The asp page returns errors when I try to access the namespace/class/function @MehbubeArman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Forms way would be something like this...

**MyPage.aspx**

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="MyLiteral" />
```

**MyPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        MyLiteral.Text=AppNamespace.App.AppDoSomething();
    }
}
```

Although slightly more PHPish, you could do this inline. But then you have the disadvantage that you can't really change it afterwards.

**MyPage.aspx**

```
<%= AppNamespace.App.AppDoSomething() %>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Coming from other languages, ASP seems... strange.

Comment: In school I was taught PHP and Java Server Pages. I learned ASP.NET for work and I really appreciate the power of the .NET framework. Sure it's a slight bit more overhead than modifying a standalone .php file, but once you start using it you'll begin to see the benefits.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC (which pretty much lets you stick C# code into a view without any big problem), you can make a reference to the dll you've made and call it via c# code.

You could either put it in the view or you could do the work of reading from the dll in the controller and stick the result in the viewbag (which you can then reference from the view).

Comment: Ok, keeping in mind I am a complete ASP noob... just plug in <body><%=AppNamespace.App.SomeFunction()%></body> right? I just want to print a value from a CS function to my asp/html page - how do I reference the .dll?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how you'd do it in webforms. I skipped over webforms in favor of using the MVC framework (which is a lot saner from the standpoint of separation of concerns, readability, etc)

Comment: I was hoping to just "echo" out a value to a blank page... do I really have to go through all the hoops of creating some whole application to get a simple value to echo out? When I compile the C# file as an .exe, it works perfectly (just writing to console). I think this is why i've always avoided .net/asp - I just want to do one simple thing without having to build an entire application to do it. Seems way over complicated... in php it would just be <? echo "something"; ?>. I'm also building my .dll's in Xamarin, I don't have Visual Studio or any microsoft compilers installed.

Comment: ASP.NET is compiled, so yeah, you pretty much have to build a project in order to do it.

It's not *complicated*, really. It's just the nature of the creature. It's not like writing a static HTML page. Sorry.